# Getting roles from my own database in .NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I want to provide a connection string from `web.config` to read only the roles - I can find many tutorials making databases with all the junk tables that come from the membership provider but I don't want any of these.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I've been doing it by creating a `FormAuthenticationTicket` and store roles in there and add them to roles on the `Global.asax` file.

If someone can point me into the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You can always implement a custom role provider, then use whatever database access library you want.

Comment: Could you point me out some good tutorials? I can only find for MVC

Comment: https://thebojan.ninja/2015/03/12/custom-role-provider/

Comment: Thanks I followed this example and managed to do it!